# postgresql: select records where ALL associated records match condition

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :abs
  has_many :bs, through: :abs
end

class AB
  belongs_to :a
  belongs_to :b
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :abs
  has_many :as, through: :abs
  # and has boolean db field :matches
end
```

So I want to implement an scope for `A` that retrieves the As where **all** it's associated Bs `matches=true`. Normally, I would do something like:

```
A.joins(:bs).where(bs: { matches: true })
```

But this will retrieve As where *at least one* b matches the conditions, not *all*.

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would instead look for records where there are zero instances of `matches: false`. I'd probably use a sub-query, something like...

```
A.joins(:bs).where('(select count(*) from bs where matches = false) = 0')
```

But there might be a more ActiveRecord way of doing it.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but PG is a little too whiny about what you put insde a WHERE statement (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE)

Comment: @nicooga Hmm. I don't know the specific syntax, but I have to assume it's easier to check `count(false) == 0` than `count(true) == count(*)`.